# Filtering elements of a matrix based on the difference between an element and the previous value

Tags: r, filter

I've got a large dataframe that I would like to apply a filter to. The condition is that if the difference between an element and it's previous value is greater than 40, I would like to set that element to NA.

Mini-data sample:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(matrix(runif(n=150, min=1, max=100), nrow=10))
```

I was able to create a matrix based on the difference between the element and its previous element fairly easily, but using that to filter the original data frame is proving tricky. This is the calculation I used to generate the difference matrix:

```
calculatedifference <- function(a) {
  difference = a - lag(a)
  difference 
}
differencematrix <- sapply(mydataframe, calculatedifference)
```

I tried the following, but it returned a dataframe filled with NA:

```
differencefilter <- function(a){
  difference = a - lag(a)
  case_when(
    difference > 40 ~ NA
  )
}
```

Probably because I am feeding case_when() an entire vector and it's setting the whole thing to NA rather than whichever elements fulfill the condition. Not sure how to sequence the command for each individual element within each vector. My original plan was to build a function for a single vector, and then sapply it to the original dataframe, but if there's a more efficient way of accomplishing the goal, that would be great too. Again, I want elements in the original mydataframe set to NA, not the values in differencematrix. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is good, the problem is that you don't set a default value for `case_when` when your condition isn't met, and `case_when`'s default default is `NA`. If you change your code to

```
case_when(
    difference > 40 ~ NA, .default = a
  )
```

I think it will work. I would go a little more directly, like this:

```
set.seed(47)
mydataframe <- data.frame(matrix(runif(n=50, min=1, max=100), nrow=5)) 

library(dplyr)

mydataframe
#         X1       X2       X3        X4       X5        X6       X7       X8        X9      X10
# 1 97.71924 69.44983 14.74096 90.295379 18.63639 38.622468 75.13312 44.52890  6.806878 21.08084
# 2 38.01769 39.51712 70.49673 40.649777 56.12284  4.342001 37.52843 24.84979 37.672119 66.51133
# 3 76.38870 47.42565 17.05717  4.063552 52.06370  4.652532 47.30130 97.66172 60.239314 96.34999
# 4 82.42667 54.78766 60.33139  8.064458 14.20961 54.107717 20.16720 48.89779 93.813872 37.83152
# 5 57.78090 92.56431 51.09757 47.363336 69.23906 80.155587 89.79590 68.70130 37.310393 85.85034

mydataframe |>
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) abs(ifelse(abs(x - lag(x, default = first(x))) > 40, NA, x))))
#         X1       X2       X3        X4       X5        X6       X7       X8        X9      X10
# 1 97.71924 69.44983 14.74096 90.295379 18.63639 38.622468 75.13312 44.52890  6.806878 21.08084
# 2       NA 39.51712       NA        NA 56.12284  4.342001 37.52843 24.84979 37.672119       NA
# 3 76.38870 47.42565       NA  4.063552 52.06370  4.652532 47.30130       NA 60.239314 96.34999
# 4 82.42667 54.78766       NA  8.064458 14.20961        NA 20.16720       NA 93.813872       NA
# 5 57.78090 92.56431 51.09757 47.363336       NA 80.155587       NA 68.70130        NA       NA


## or using case_when in case you have more conditions
mydataframe |>
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x)
    case_when(
      abs(x - lag(x)) > 40 ~ NA, 
      .default = x
    )
))
## same result as above
```

Comment: You have to consider the absoluteness. ie column 2 rows 6,7 the difference is greater than 40.

Comment: Also note that OP stated that *if the difference between an element and it's previous value is greater than 40, I would like to set that element to NA.* Meaning the current number is the one to be changed to `NA` and not the previous number. eg column 1 rows 1,2 the 2nd number should change to `NA` and not the first number

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This works great, but I am actually going to use the edit on my own solution so I can fiddle around with the case_when() filter levels (as pointed out by Onyambu, I realized I needed the absolute values as well, though I think I'll just make that a secondary case_when condition) and build them out as needed for my own purposes, but your solution is quite efficient.

Comment: Sounds good, `ifelse` is nice when there are only 2 cases, but for more `case_when` is nicer.  You can use `case_when` in my solution, see edits...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterating over rows or columns, I would use `data.frame` operations. Let's just create a slightly smaller data frame as an example.

```r
(mydataframe <- data.frame(
    a = c(10, 20, 100),
    b = c(10, 100, 100)
))
    a   b
1  10  10
2  20 100
3 100 100
```

We can create a data frame shifted by one row, and subtract that from the original data frame to create a logical mask of values to set as `NA`:

```r
mydataframe[
    mydataframe - rbind(mydataframe[1, ], head(mydataframe, -1)) > 40
]  <- NA

   a   b
1 10  10
2 20  NA
3 NA 100
```

I've assumed you want to keep the first row but if not subtract `mydataframe - rbind(rep(-Inf, ncol(mydataframe)), head(mydataframe, -1)) > 40` instead.